# How can I implement modular constants in Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

In Firebase functions I've discovered the possibility of separating functions into their own separate files for maintainability. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions) is the documentation I followed for this.

I'm now trying to figure out how to implement modular string constants that I can import into my new modular function files.

I've tried the following syntax:

- `const exports.string1 = "myString1"`
- `exports const.string2 = "myString2"`

I'm using JavaScript, not TypeScript and the Node.js 10 runtime.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about Cloud Functions.  You can use the standard procedures for nodejs.

To export:

```
exports.string1 = "myString1";
```

To import:

```
const module = require("./your-module");
const string1 = module.string1;
```

Comment: Thank you Doug for everything you've done with Firebase and for being so active on here. It is a fantastic product.

Answer (score 1):

You export like this:

```
exports.string1 = "myString1"
```

and than import:

```
const module = require('./filename');
```